# How do you convert a file in memory to a byte array?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I am using IonicZip to compress video files and store in a blob field.  I have the zip file created just need to convert it to a byte array.  How is this done without writing to the harddrive?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write to a MemoryStream, you can use the "ToArray()" method on the MemoryStream to get a byte array.

Comment: How do you convert the IonicZip file that is in memory to a Memory Stream?

Comment: Most ZIP libraries have an overload of their Save method that takes a MemoryStream instead of a filename.  If IonicZip provides that, simply create a new MemoryStream, pass it to the Save method then use ToArray() to get the byte array.